# no public access to objects properties?

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to show data from mysql database. I successfully created an entity but somehow can't access the properties, although I have public setters and getters.

Error Message:

> Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "id()", "getid()"/"isid()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Todos"

I also tried differend namings but nothing seem to work. I'm also able to dump the object so it has to be there but I just can't get its values

controller function:

```
public function listToDo(){
    $todos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Todos::class)->findAll();
    return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig', ['todos'=>$todos]);
}
```

Todos.php:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Todos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="todos")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Todos 
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ToDo", type="text", length=65535, nullable=false)
     */
    private $todo;

    /**
     * Get id
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getid(){
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get todo
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function gettodo(){
        return $this->todo;
    }

    public function setTodo($todo){
        $this->todo = $todo;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

index.html.twig:

```
...
{% for do in todos %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ dump(do) }}</td>
        <td>{{ do.id }}</td>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %} 
...
```

Anybody has an idea to solve this?

Comment: You can try changing getid() to getId() though I don't think it will help.  Good to be consistent though.  And of course do the ever popular clearing of the cache.

Comment: Still having trouble with this?  Just wondering what the solution was (if any).

Comment: Somehow there was a mistake in the projectstructure and I had this entity two times...

Comment: Hate it when that happens.  Thanks for the follow up.

Answer (score 2):

try to replace

```
public function getid(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function gettodo(){
    return $this->todo;
}
```

with

```
public function getId(){
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTodo(){
    return $this->todo;
}
```

Comment: I also tried to set the attributes public but even that isn't working

Answer (score 0):

getid() and gettodo() is not valid cameCase format.
you should rename methods to **getId()** and **getTodo()**